# series of functions and term by term differentiation

Tags: real-analysis

We know that if an infinite series of functions $\sum f_n$ converges at some point and $\sum f'_n$ converges uniformly, then $(\sum f_n)' = \sum f_n'$. But is it true for partial derivatives? That is, if $f$ is multivariable function, does the same can be said for its partial derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for the  reason that partial derivatives are ordinary derivatives of the *restriction* of a function to a line. Let's say we look at point $(1,2,3)$ and the $x$-derivative of $f$ at that point. Consider the restrictions of $f_n$ and $f$ to the line $y=2$, $z=3$. The series of restricted functions converges pointwise at $x=1$, and its $x$-derivatives converge uniformly, by assumption. Therefore, the single variable result applies: the $x$-derivative  of the sum is the sum of $x$-derivatives.